# ORA-01841: el valor (completo) del año debe estar entre -4713 y +9999, y no debe ser igual a 0

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

El problema que tengo es que en Dbeaver , el gestor de base de datos mi consulta , si me arroja resultados:

```
SELECT * FROM ENVIO_REMESA er where er.FECHA_ENVIO >= TO_DATE('2021-04-26', 'YYYY-mm-DD');
```

En cambio en Hibernate , no me arroja ningún resultado , y me salta el error que pone en el título  `ORA-01841: el valor (completo) del año debe estar entre -4713 y +9999, y no debe ser igual a 0`.
Mi consulta en el repository es esta:

```
     @Query("SELECT e FROM EnvioRemesa e WHERE e.fechaEnvio >= TO_DATE('?1','YYYY-mm-DD')")
     Page<EnvioRemesa> findAllPorFecha(String fecha,Pageable pageable);
```

Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Comment: El problema puede ser el formato de la cadena fecha, ¿le llega exactamente como aparece en la query de arriba? Compruébalo porque parece que ahí radica tu problema.

Comment: Acabo de ver que pasaba, he respondido con la solución. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema..

```
 @Query("SELECT e FROM EnvioRemesa e WHERE e.fechaEnvio >= TO_DATE(?1,'YYYY-mm-DD')")
```

Al recibir un String no es necesario hacer '?1' , sino que lo correcto es ?1

Comment: No es necesario con strings ni con ningún otro tipo. Los `?` son *placeholders* que el programa luego va a sustituir, y al sustituirlos ya se encarga de añadirlos de manera correcta! No necesitas indicarle nada, ya tratará bien el tipo, los espacios en medio... todo.

Comment: Gracias por explicar la solución. Puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada para que otras personas tengan más fácil encontrarla.